# Why is field name Location blue

Tags: sql-server

I have a table field named "Location".  When I use that field name in my stored procedures, it is blue.  I understand (incorrectly?) that that indicates that it is a reserved word.  Yet I have reviewed both the current and future reserved word lists for SQL Server and Location is not listed.  Is the use of Location as a table field name problematic for any reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a reserved word.

It is a key word that [exists in the grammar though](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-table-transact-sql).

```
-- Create a new external table  
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [ database_name . [ schema_name ] . | schema_name. ] table_name   
    ( <column_definition> [ ,...n ] )  
    WITH (   
        LOCATION = 'folder_or_filepath',  
        DATA_SOURCE = external_data_source_name,  
        FILE_FORMAT = external_file_format_name  
        [ , <reject_options> [ ,...n ] ]  
    )  
[;]
```

So SSMS will highlight it as a keyword. There are no ill effects from using it as an identifier name -  apart from possibly finding the syntax highlighting distracting when the identifier name is not quoted with square brackets or quote marks.

Answer (score 0):

> Is the use of Location as a table field name problematic for any reason?

No problem at all. You can use square brackets around the column names for safety, then you can even use reserved words.

Comment: You *can use* reserved keywords - but it's still a bad practice and should be avoided if at all possible

Comment: I am aware of the use of brackets; I was just curious as to why it was "blued".